How to dynamic import chai in CommonJS?
chai latest version 5.1.2 move to ESModule. Is it possible continue use it in CommonJS file? chai is just a dev dependency in my project, used for unit test. I don't want to upgrade my modules to ESModule.
I tried below code:
const expect = (...args) => import('chai').then((mod) => mod.expect(...args));
expect ('true').to.equal('false');

It will report below error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equal')

Below code works, but I don't want to add this for each expect. I have lots of expect statements.
import('chai').then(chai => {
  expect = chai.expect;
  expect('true').to.equal('false');
  
});

Another option is add a line like below
const expectEqual = (arg1, arg2) => import('chai').then((mod) => mod.expect(arg1).to.equal(arg2));

That means I need to add declare for all types of expect. expect.to.be, expect.to.deep.equal...
Is there any better way to dynamic import chai in CommonJS?

in your commonJS module try something like that:
const importExpect = async () => await import('chai').then((chai) => chai.expect);

(async () => {
    const expect = await importExpect()
    // your old tests
    expect('true').to.equal('true');
    // your old tests
})()

